# Set .Caption property of inactive userform label from other userform

Tags: vba, userform, designer

I have a userform that allows users to input text that will be sent to another userform by calling the following function, where `targetLabel` is the intended control to accept the caption `revisedStr`:

```
Function changeMsgLabel(ByRef targetLabel As String, revisedStr As String)

    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("masterMsgUserForm").Designer
        With .Controls(targetLabel)
            .Caption = revisedStr
        End With
    End With
  
End Function
```

I've used code blocks similar in this project to this one before with success, setting the `.Name` property of controls, but for some reason this gives me the error `Object or with block variable not set`. For full disclosure, the names of both the label and the userform are correct and the necessary libraries are included.

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: Sorry. The With .Controls(targetLbl) line.

Comment: Your code seems fine.  However, you'll get that error if `masterMsgUserForm` is displayed/shown.

Comment: It’s not active. Never Initialized.

Comment: Is the label nested in another control like a frame for example?

Comment: It is in a frame, yes

Comment: That works for me....

Comment: Does it make a difference if the userform that prompts for the message input is initialized by clicking a button on another userform that remains active?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to make any difference.